# Navigation bar disappear

Tags: ios, xcode

When i do as the Xcode doc says, on "Your second iOS App", after i add some code, the navigation bar just disappeared.
i believe i didn't add some code associated with the bar. 
what can i do to take it back?

and my issue is different from this body's [Navigation bar disappeared from my storyboard items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287963/navigation-bar-disappeared-from-my-storyboard-items)

Thanks a lot. sorry to have not enough reputation to post a pic

Comment: At least give us a link for the pic. That will help a lot ;)

Comment: the constraint conflicts, i'm gonna reset them, and try it over again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, so bad. I was nervous at that time. So i do it again with starting a complete code. I didn't remember the problem i got.

Answer (score 0):

Did you complete the BirdWatching app and then added the code? Did you mess with the navigation controller in the Main.storyboard by any chance?